# Comparing two arrays character by character perl

Tags: arrays, string, perl, compare, character

I have two arrays:

@Array1 which contains A,B,C,D,E

and

@Array2 which contains L,B,C,F,E

I tried using a foreach to go through every element in the arrays and say if it's true or not to get started but I get dirty big fat errors when doing anything.

The program works perfectly with one foreach, but with a nested one it bugs out:

```
foreach my $var (@Array1){
       print "Letter $var";
        foreach my $var2 (@Array2){
        if($var2 eq $var) {
            print "They are equal";
        } else {
            next;
        }
    }
}
```

Any Ideas; one error is:

Use of uninitialized value in string eq at compare.pl line 192, <> line 2.

Comment: Forget the ours! My mistake in copying I will edit. The arrays were made earlier on in program...

Comment: That was a very strange edit you made... I'm sorry, but there is no point in removing the tags or changing the code so it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @Array1=qw/A B C D E/;
my @Array2=qw/L B C F E/;

foreach my $var (@Array1){
       $\=$/;
       print "Letter $var";
        foreach my $var2 (@Array2){
        if($var2 eq $var) {
            print "They are equal";
        } else {
            next;
        }
    }
}
```

and I've got it

```
Letter A
Letter B
They are equal
Letter C
They are equal
Letter D
Letter E
They are equal
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error means one of the values in either array is undefined. Since you do not show how the arrays are assigned values, it is impossible to tell why. It is clear that the problem lies in code you do not show.

What you can do to debug the problem is to print the arrays with the [`Data::Dumper`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data%3a%3aDumper) module:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@Array1, \@Array2;
```

Then you should see what values they contain.

Also:

- It is quite unnecessary to use your `else { next }` block, since it is the last part of the loop.
- Printing "They are equal" would be quite a useless statement for bigger arrays, since you would get output that states that something is equal to something else, but you would only know one of the elements.

Comment: It was mainly for debug purposes just to show if it was working. I am well aware of getting it to see which is equal. Regardlesss this has helped, thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to use array_diff(@arr1, @arr2) 
of [Array::Utils](http://search.cpan.org/~zmij/Array-Utils-0.5/Utils.pm).

Answer (score 0):

As TLP says one of the values in the array is undef.
You can change the code to something like this to solve the problem.

```
    foreach my $var (@Array1){
           print "Letter $var \n";
            foreach my $var2 (@Array2){
            #(Both are undef (so they match)) OR (both are defined AND MATCH)
            if((!defined($var2) && !defined($var)) || 
                 (defined($var2) && defined( $var) && ($var2 eq $var))) {
                print "They are equal\n";
            } else {
                next;
            }
        }
    }
```